# Proof combining accumulation point and limits of function for $\lim_{x\to c} \sqrt {f(x)} = \sqrt L $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f:D \to R $ and let $c$ be an accumulation point of $D$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$

If $f(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x\in D$, prove that $\lim_{x\to c} \sqrt {f(x)}  = \sqrt L $

How would you even start this proof? Right away I can spot that there are two cases when $L=0$ and $L\ne 0$.  So I think I have to do two cases is that correct?

Comment: Think of function composition.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: It is generally the case that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow c f(x)=L$ and $g$ is continuous at $L$ then $g(\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)) =g(L)$. Can you prove that?